# use of 'static constexpr auto A::f()' before deduction of 'auto'

Tags: c++

This code won't compile:

```
struct A{
    static constexpr auto f(){
        return []{};
    }
    static constexpr auto x = f();
};
```

*error: use of 'static constexpr auto A::f()' before deduction of 'auto'*

I know there are multiple questions similar to this one but I really don't understand what in this specific case is preventing the compiler from doing its job.
Also notice that the same code, outside a class definition, works perfectly.

Comment: C++ has some twisted rules when defining in-class members - declarations are processed first and definitions later - it makes it possible to use members that will be declared later. So return type of `f` will be known only after class is completely defined and no other member declaration may depend on it. That is when declaring other members `f` appears like `static constexpr auto f();`

Comment: Ok. It makes sense. And it's good to know